# Connect to Azure Synapse for data from local development environment

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-synapse

Is it possible to connect to Azure Synapse for data from local development environment?

We just finished a project to develop models using Azure Synapse Studio in browser. The dev experience was mixed so I am currently trying to find ways to setup local development environment which can use Synapse data but everything else (Aanconda, VSCode/Pycharm, etc.) is local. That way I would only leverage synapse to connect to data.

I did try researching but haven't had much success. Below are some relevant links I tried.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1043205/is-it-possible-to-connect-visual-studio-code-with

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/get-started-azure-data-studio

Comment: Please read [ask] and how to write a [mcve].

Comment: @DavidMakogon I understand. I will try to add more details to the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of SSMS to connect to Synapse from your local development environment. Go to the overview of the Synapse workspace and copy the endpoint:

[image]

Paste the endpoint, enter the admin and password, and click on "Connect" in SSMS to connect as shown below:

[image]

It will connect the workspace as shown below:

[image]

Alternatively, you can connect to Synapse using the Python code below in Anaconda, PyCharm, or VSCode:

```
import pyodbc

server = '<serverName>.sql.azuresynapse.net'
database = '<dbName>'
username = '<userName>'
password = '<password>'
driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
connection_string = f'DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password}'
connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM student')
rows = cursor.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

It will connect to the Synapse workspace successfully as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your response. Can you please provide more information about drivers we need to install? Your code mentions about driver on line 7.

Comment: You can download and install odbc driver from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: The question is off-topic - there's no effort shown, just a requirement and some links. Please don't answer off-topic questions. Rather, provide appropriate guidance for improving the question.

Comment: @DavidMakogon , I followed the link shared but none is pointing to what we need. Also, I have not been able to find a documentation to connect VS/Pycharm to Synapse and do dev locally. Answer link above does provide a direction.